# Enforce child class to implement a UI property, Swift Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, inheritance, uiviewcontroller

**UPDATE**
I solved this question, in the sense, that I got what I wanted on some levels of Do Not Repeat Yourself, see here:

[Using the same property name/reference for Outlets in a base class and potential bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34408028/using-the-same-property-name-reference-for-outlets-in-a-base-class-and-potential/34408136#34408136)

But I still want to leave this question up as someone might share some uses of base classes and protocols that might provide more elegant solutions then what I came up with.

I have a super class called `UITabBarTopLevelViewController`, it inherits from `UIViewController`. I then have some UIViewControllers that I want to inherit from the base class `UITabBarTopLevelViewController`.

What I want the child classes to do is implement a `UINavigationItem` property, that is part of a `UINavigationBar` and the `UINavigationBar` is in the super `UIView` for each `UIViewController: UITabBarTopLevelViewController`. I could, for example, in UIViewController , add the following:

```
@IBOutlet weak var uiNavItemTitle: UINavigationItem!
```

Of course the `UINavigationItem` exists in the Story Board because I dragged a `UINavigationBar` onto the `UIViewController`.

But, what I rather do, is ensure implementation of a property called `uiNavItemTitle`, and its type `UINavigationItem`, and then also access the property in my base class: `UITabBarTopLevelViewController`.

If I create a `Protocol` and inherit from that in my base class `UITabBarTopLevelViewController` that doesn't seem like the right direction as the property, `uiNavItemTitle: UINavigationItem` doesn't exist there, its in the child `UIViewController` that inherits from `UITabBarTopLevelViewController`.

If, for each child UIViewController I have the following class definition:

```
class ChildViewController: UITabBarTopLevelViewController, MyProtocol
```

This kind of works as the `MyProtocol` can enforce a property to be implemented in `ChildViewController` but then every `ChildViewController` has to remember to inherit the `UITabBarTopLevelViewController` base class and the `MyProtocol` protocol and that also does not give me a way to access the property `uiNavItemTitle: UINavigationItem` in my base class `UITabBarTopLevelViewController`.

My goal is that I want to set the same logo in 5 Views and all 5 Views have a UINavigationBar and a UINavigationItem and I am setting the `UINavigationItem.titleView`.

I would like to set the logo in one place for all 5 views and enforce the 5 views using a Base class and or Protocol to implement the `uiNavItemTitle: UINavigationItem`, as well as ensure that the `uiNavItemTitle: UINavigationItem` property exists at runtime and is accessible to the base class `UITabBarTopLevelViewController`.

Perhaps I am just over thinking it and I need to handle this in each of the views. I already did create a function that can be called from all 5 views and that function creates the UIImageView logo I need, so that simplifies my code.

I also could create a Custom UI Component but I feel like I need to inherit from `UIView` for my Custom UI Component as inheriting from `UINavigationBar` will not give me runtime access to UINavigationItem to set the titleView to my logo. `UINavigationBar` has no `viewDidLoad`. And if my Custom UI Component is a UIView it will need height settings and what I want is the `UINavigationBar` "default" height like it is when I drag into a UIView in the Xcode Story Board.

I feel like I am getting an easy height conforming header across different IPhone devices, using a UINavigationBar and if I use a UIView as the super view containing the UINavigationBar in a Custom UI Component, I will be playing height guessing games of some kind across different iPhone devices or have unexpected height results in certain resolution screens. Not to mention that I will have to resize my super view below a UIView Custom UI Component and I think Swift automatically fits the super view below the UINavigationBar.