# Using the same property name/reference for Outlets in a base class and potential bugs

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

So I have a base class UIViewController called `UITabBarTopLevelViewController`:

```
class UITabBarTopLevelViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var uiNavItemTitle: UINavigationItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    uiNavItemTitle.titleView = CoreUtility.LogoForUINavBarGet()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

I then have two UIViewControllers that inherit from my base class and both look like this, except the second is called `MyViewController2`:

```
class MyViewController1: UITabBarTopLevelViewController {

//@IBOutlet weak var uiNavItemTitle: UINavigationItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //uiNavItemTitle.titleView = CoreUtility.LogoForUINavBarGet()

}
```

I add a Navigation Bar object to each child UIViewController super view and then I CTRL drag and add a new outlet to each UIViewController child class:

[image]

And here is the second CTRL drag outlet:

[image]

These are different references, but I can comment out the `@IBOutlet weak var uiNavItemTitle: UINavigationItem!` in my child classes and reference one time only in the base class `UITabBarTopLevelViewController`, for both `MyViewController1` and `MyViewController2`.

You can see, when I hover over the outlet circle, in my base class, it highlights both UINavigationItem in the Story Board:

[image]

I am surprised this works, its nice for me that it works because I only need to set the `uiNavItemTitle.titleView` for my logo one time for both views. This is what I want but there seems to be a bit of magic that I can reference multiple outlet references one time in my base class and there is no bugs or crashes.

I currently have no memory leaks or crashes and my app is working just fine and doing exactly as I desire.

**Will there be any bugs with this?**

**Could someone explain how this is working?**

**Is the fact that this works, not surprising to experienced Swift developers?**

Answer (score 1):

That's how subclass exactly works.

You placed a `UINavigationItem` in the base class `UITabBarTopLevelViewController` through

> uiNavItemTitle.titleView = CoreUtility.LogoForUINavBarGet()

Also, `MyViewController1` and `MyViewController2` inherit from the base class `UITabBarTopLevelViewController`. That's say these child viewControllers both *have* a UINavigationItem which inherit from their `UITabBarTopLevelViewController`.

This is not a bug, on the other hand, more like a topic about *design pattern* though. You could place all the *base* stuff into a base class, inherit from those classes and implement the specific detail within the child class.

HTH.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense from an object oriented perspective, I just see weak with @IBOutlets and I think its some kind of special reference and I am going against the grain of how it works.

Comment: Maybe this can help you. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/AboutConnectingObjectstoCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014227-CH42-SW1